# Adding buttons over the backgroud image in xml android

Tags: android, button, background

I am trying to add Buttons over the background in xml android same as in the given screen shot image.The buttons are placed over the background.[image: see this screenshot image]
Can any one here tell me that how to add a button over the background image in XML.Is it possible by using XML?

In which layout type and how it will be possible for me. Linear layout/frame layout or relative layout. 
kindly give code snippet for this scenario.

Comment: take linearlayout and set background of layout with your image and then you can add button. if you tried this then post your code.

Comment: Post your code. A person will edit and post again it as answer.

Comment: ok i got it thanks for the help. but tell me one thing how can i set coordinates or location of the button as per my requirement. which remains constant on each n every phone. means the location of the button does not change by installing the app on different phones.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Relative Layout here as a parent layout and then set image in background of layout. It will work.

Comment: ok i got it thanks for the help. but tell me one thing how can i set coordinates or location of the button as per my requirement. which remains constant on each n every phone. means the location of the button does not change by installing the app on different phones.

Comment: u can use different dimens folder available to make it look consistent in all size phones

Answer (score 0):

Add background for your layout from drawable resource file. It will work.

```
android:background="@drawable/background_bg"
```